# Formula 1.2 in book "Volatility Trading" by Euan Sinclair

Tags: option-pricing, volatility

I am reading "Volatility Trading" by Euan Sinclair. In the derivation of BSM process in Chapter 1, formula 1.2 confused me.

[image: This is the scriptshot]

It means that the value change of a hedged call position (1 Call $C_t$ and $\Delta$ short stocks).

The last term from author denotes the interest income, which is from the financing to build the position for the hedged option.

However, in my understanding, to build a position of a hedged call, you borrow money of $C(S_t)$ to buy the Call option, then short Delta stocks and lending the proceedings of $\Delta S_t$ which makes you receive $r(\Delta S_t-C)$ interest income instead of $r(C-\Delta S_t)$.

Any one can explain me which one should be correct?

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is correct, this has been corrected in [the second edition](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Volatility+Trading%2C+%2B+Website%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781118416723) on Page 3:

[image]

Comment: I am a bit at a loss as to the downvote, is my answer incorrect? I am happy to retract the answer if this is the case.